# Users of Intranet site on IIS7.5 prompted for username/password

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have an intrasite from a third-party that we just transitioned from IIS 6 on Windows 2003 to a Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS 7.5.  On the old system, the user would connect ot the website and be automatically authenticated and be able to view the pages.

Now on the new server, the user is presented with a username/password prompt, like Basic Auth.  If they type in their domain username and password, it'll authenticate them.

I'm trying to figure out why it's not doing automatic Windows authentication.  I've verifie that the website "Authentication" tab only has Windows authentication turned on, no Basic or other methods are supported.  I also went into Providers and set it to only use NTLM.  I used Policy Editor to make several adjustments to the NTLM security settings and LAN Manager to allow NTLM.

The client browser is IE 8 and it has Windows Integration Authentication enabled.

I'm at a complete loss as to why the automatic Windows authentication isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the new site URL to the trusted sites list in IE and give it another shot.

Comment: For testing, I needed to do this and alter the trust settings to allow logon always (rather than for intranet). In any case, this helped towards the solution. Thanks!